# Get checked checkbox values in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I am new to codeigniter. I wanted to know how to get checkbox values which are checked .I went through various answers but couldnt solve.

I am displaying the values from database table as checkbox values.

**My view code for checkbox :**

```
<?php foreach($g->result() as $grp) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck[]" value="<?php  echo $grp->group_id; ?>"<?php echo set_checkbox('mycheck', '$grp->group_id;' ); ?> /><?php  echo $grp->group_name; ?>
```

I don not know how to get only the  checked value(that is the group_id) in **controller** as well as in **model** to insert it into another tabel in database..

**Please help.**

Comment: is this solved ??

Comment: yes ,Thankyou for asking.

Answer (score 1):

In your view

```
   <?php 
   foreach($g->result() as $grp) 
   { 
   ?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="mycheck[]" value="<?php echo $grp->group_id; ?>">
   <?php 
   } 
   ?>
```

Now in your controller function

```
if(!empty($this->input->post('mycheck')))
 {
foreach ( $this->input->post('mycheck') as $obj)
    {
        $mycheck[]= $obj; 
    }
 }
 $returnvalue = $this->modelname->samplefn($mycheck); // pass value to model fn
```

Now inside your model function use **where_in** instead of where like below

```
function samplefn($mycheck)
    {
       $query = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('tablename')
                    ->where_in('checkboxcol', $mycheck)
                    ->get();

       if($query->num_rows()>0)
       {
        // echo $this->db->last_query()."<br>";
        return $query->result();  // return an array of objects
       }
       else
       {
        return null;
       } 
    }
```

To insert multiple values in database

```
 function samplefninsert()
    {
      $checkboxes = $this->input->post('mycheck');
      foreach($checkboxes as $obj)
      {
         $this->db->insert('yourtablename',array('yourcheckboxfieldname'=>$obj));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response.I also needed to know how can i store the values in 'returnvalue' in another table. I tired printign the value 'returnvalue' using 2 methods 1) simply printing returnvalue in a view 2) by giving :" $returnvalue['i'] = $this->modelname->samplefn($mycheck) " in controller and in view : <?php 
   foreach($i->result() as $id) 
   { 
   ?> <?php echo $id; ?>. But it is showing error

Comment: @Anna  try this <?php  foreach($i as $id) { ?> <?php echo $id->yourfieldname ; ?> <?php } ?>  in your view

Comment: Yes it is working :) But it is taking only one value. Its not taking multiple checkbox values. I needed that. Can you please help @geordy ?

Comment: @Anna I edited the code to include insertion method too. i also updated select function ( use $query->result() insead of $query->row() since row() can only return one value )

Comment: Its showing error : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.               Else can you tell me how to print the values in $mycheck (that is the group_id in my case) in another view. Or how to get the values in $mycheck. $mycheck has got all the values of checked check boxes.

Comment: @Anna where did you got that error. Specify error code. You need to insert each check box value one by one.

Comment: i get the error in view page where i tried displaying it. Here: <?php foreach($i as $id) { ?>
  <?php echo $id ; ?> 
  <?php } ?> .this error ahppenswhen i changed to $query->result() .

Comment: @Anna you need to specify field name too. <?php foreach($i as $id) { ?> <?php echo $id->databasefieldname ; ?> <?php } ?> and to get multiple value you need to use $query->result() too

Answer (score 0):

If your form has been successfully submitted you should see in your controller an array of data

```
$this->input->post_get()
```

in your case look for

```
$this->input->post_get('mycheck')
```

Take a look to the documentation of CodeIgniter [Input Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) for more informations.

Comment: Thankyou for the response

Comment: Since i am very new to the framework. I wasnt able to implement yours